# cannot monit puma server with Monit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monit

my mmonit config file:

```
  check process qifu with pidfile /var/www/qifu/tmp/pids/puma.pid
    start program = "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/qifu && pumactl -F config/puma_production.rb start'" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/qifu && pumactl -F config/puma_production.rb stop'"
    if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
    if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

It works when I execute the start and stop command directly from terminal, but mmonit not works.

Comment: need to mention the error returned by monit. I think it's a privilege error, need use user from sudoers group, or something like that

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to switch user. Try changing your commands to start with `/bin/su - <user> -c` so your code becomes:

```
check process qifu with pidfile /var/www/qifu/tmp/pids/puma.pid
    start program = "/bin/su - <user> -c 'cd /var/www/qifu && pumactl -F config/puma_production.rb start'" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/bin/su - <user> -c 'cd /var/www/qifu && pumactl -F config/puma_production.rb stop'"
    if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
    if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```